# How to calculate minimum image scale?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, image-scaling

I need to setup a [jQuery UI slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#rangemin) as an image scaler, yet I need to make sure that it is restricted on the low end to meet minimum size requirements.

Given that I know the following:

- existing image dimensions
- minimum width and height
- all scales are to be proportional

... how do I calculate the minimum scale (as in a percentage) so that scale of the image meets the minimum width and height requirements?

Let me know if that wasn't clear, and I'll try to clarify.

Comment: as you predicted it's not clear :) would be great if you give some numeric example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var minWidth = 100,
   minHeight = 100,
    curWidth = 600,
   curHeight = 800,
        minW = minWidth / curWidth,
        minH = minHeight / curHeight 

    minScale = Math.max(minW, minH); // .1666666666
```